# Wikidata SPARQL Query

Tags: sparql, wikidata

On [Wikidata's SPARQL endpoint](https://query.wikidata.org), I want to find all the universities where someone was employed as a university teacher. So far, I managed to get the triples of type (person, position helf, employer) with the following query:

```
PREFIX bd: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX v: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX pq: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/qualifier/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?sp ?q ?sLabel ?spLabel ?qLabel WHERE {
  ?s p:P39 ?p .
  ?p v:P39 ?sp .
  ?p pq:P108 ?q .
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
  }
}
```

This query returns all the positions held by that person. In my case, I want to limit myself to the held position of university teacher (wd:Q1622272).

If possible, I would ask for a simplified query.

Comment: If `?sp` denotes the held position, does it not work to replace it by `wd:Q1622272` then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the variable `?sp` with the specific position you want (i.e. `wd:Q1622272`) in the triple pattern `?p v:P39 ?sp .`:

```
PREFIX bd: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX v: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX pq: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/qualifier/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?q ?sLabel ?qLabel WHERE {
  ?s p:P39 ?p .
  ?p v:P39 wd:Q1622272 . # Here
  ?p pq:P108 ?q .
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
  }
}
```